# NetSuite - CSV Importing Sales Order Issue

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

When I try to do a CSV import of sales order data I get - **Please specify a discount item for this customer** error.

On the sales order there is a discount item field which we don't use. I've tried setting it to null when doing the import field mappings but doesn't accept it.

The field in the form is populated with the values 'discount' and 'partner discount' - where in the system is this set and how can we do the import without this field?

EDIT:

I see the issue - I was setting the form 'rate' field rather than the line item 'rate'.

Comment: Have you looked in the customer record for the discount level? I'm not sure where this field would be set to mandatory for all sales orders, but you could try all the various sales order forms and see if the field is set to mandatory. Also any workflows or scripts that require this field could cause issues.

Comment: I did - I can't seem to find any discount level fields set anywhere. Also - on the form it is not set to mandatory. It's only in the import that it asks for it.There's no wf or script that's setting it to mandatory either.

Answer (score 1):

Check the amount field in your mapping. NetSuite auto-maps any csv column with the header of "Amount" to the Discount Amount field. That is why it is looking for a Discount Item.

Comment: I have the amount field mapped to my amount column in CSV. If I remove the amount field mapping it errors saying it needs amount even though on the form itself amount can be calculated - quantity * rate = amount.

Comment: @TonyH and Rusty - out of interest..it seems we also need to specify a Order# - given that this is auto-generated why do we need to map this for? Even if I map this with values in my CSV - it's not used, it still auto generates them so it doesn't make sense why I even need to map this.

Comment: Must be because the Order # is like the transaction id of the record and it is a required field.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on another site.  The rate at the invoice level is the discount rate, so it is looking for a discount item.  You need to select the rate at the item level, the same place you found the amount field.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was promotion code that was issue, I changed it and it stopped asking for discount price again.